# C : memory management

Tags: c, memory-management, conditional-statements, dynamic-memory-allocation

How do I free up memory based on these conditions?: If used memory is < 25% of the capacity of the system, free up 50% of unused memory.

See: freeMemoryConditional method in the dlist class

Questions:

How do you check the size of a dlist (used or unused memory slots included)?

How do you check whether a dlist node has an occupied memory slot?

Here is my code attempt:

```
#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0

typedef struct s_elem elem;

struct s_elem {
    int value;
    elem *next;
    elem *prev;
};

typedef struct {
    elem *topL;
    elem *topR;
    elem *head;
    elem *tail;
    int size;
} dlist;

void dl_initialise(dlist *dl);
void dl_initialise_block(dlist *dl, int num_elems);
void dl_push(dlist *dl, int value, int is_left_stack);
int dl_pop(dlist *dl, int is_left_stack);
void dl_print(dlist *dl);
void dl_freeMemory(dlist *dl); //edited
void dl_freeMemoryConditional(dlist *dl); //edited
```

dlist

```
/*
    dlist: a dynamic data structure that implements a doubly linked list of int values and allows being filled in a stack-like fashion both at its left or right sides.
    functions push and pop are available, and push ensures that the left and righ hand side stacks do not collide. 
    It also reserves the first element of the list to the left hand side stack, and the final element to the right hand side of the stack.
    dlist is normally initialised to 2 elements: the head and the tail.
    -- This implementation is not thread safe. --
*/

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "dlist.h"

// initialises a dlist, creating the elements head and tail
void dl_initialise(dlist *dl) {
    dl->head = malloc(sizeof(elem));
    dl->head->prev = NULL;
    dl->tail = malloc(sizeof(elem));
    dl->head->next = dl->tail;
    dl->tail->prev = dl->head;
    dl->tail->next = NULL;
    dl->head->value = -1;
    dl->tail->value = -1;
    dl->topL = NULL;
    dl->topR = NULL;
    dl->size = 2;
}

// initialises a new block, increasing the available space in a dlist
void dl_initialise_block(dlist *dl, int num_elems) {

    if(num_elems < 1)
        return;

    elem *current;
    if(dl->topL)
        current = dl->topL;
    else
        current = dl->head;
    int i = num_elems;
    while(i-- > 0) {
        current->next = malloc(sizeof(elem));
        current->next->prev = current;
        current = current->next;
        current->value = -1;
    }
    if(dl->topR) {
        current->next = dl->topR;
        dl->topR->prev = current;
    } else {
        current->next = dl->tail;
        dl->tail->prev = current;
    }
    dl->size += num_elems;
}

// push operation as in a stack - takes into account the side
void dl_push(dlist *dl, int value, int is_left_stack) {
    if(is_left_stack) {
        if(dl->topL != NULL && (dl->topL->next == dl->topR || dl->topL->next == dl->tail))
            dl_initialise_block(dl, dl->size);
        if(dl->topL)
            dl->topL = dl->topL->next;
        else
            dl->topL = dl->head;
        dl->topL->value = value;
    } else {
        if(dl->topR != NULL && (dl->topR->prev == dl->topL || dl->topR->prev == dl->head))
            dl_initialise_block(dl, dl->size);
        if(dl->topR)
            dl->topR = dl->topR->prev;
        else
            dl->topR = dl->tail;
        dl->topR->value = value;
    }
}

// pop operation as in a stack - takes into account the side
int dl_pop(dlist *dl, int is_left_stack) {
    int res;
    if(is_left_stack && dl->topL) {
        res = dl->topL->value;
        dl->topL->value = -1;
        dl->topL = dl->topL->prev;
    } else if(!is_left_stack && dl->topR) {
        res = dl->topR->value;
        dl->topR->value = -1;
        dl->topR = dl->topR->next;
    }
    return res;
}

// free up the memory occupied by a dlist
void dl_freeMemory(dlist *dl) {

    elem *current = dl->head;
    elem *next;

    while(current != NULL) {
    next = current->next;
    free(current);
    current = next;
    }
}

// conditional memory free-up
void dl_freeMemoryConditional(dlist *dl) {

    elem *current = dl->head;
    elem *next;
    //elem *temp;
    int size = dl->size;
    int capacity = 0;

    //check capacity
    while(current = !NULL) {
        next = current->next;
        capacity++;
        current = next;
    }

    current = dl->head; 

    //free 50% of memory if <25% is in use
    if(size < (capacity/4)){
        //temp = current;
        while(current = !NULL) {
            next = current->next;
            if(rand() % 2 > 0) {
                free(current);
            //} else {
                //temp = current;
            }
        current = next;
        }
    }
}

// print the full contents of a dlist
void dl_print(dlist *dl) {
    elem *current = dl->head;
    printf("DList contents:\n");
    // comment

    while(current != NULL) {
        printf("%d ", current->value);
        current = current->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

main

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "dlist.h"

dlist dl; // main structure used in the program

// worker thread function
void* do_work(void *p_isL) {
    int isL = *((int *)p_isL);
    int current = 0;

    while (current < 50) {

        pthread_mutex_t count_mutex;

        pthread_mutex_lock(&count_mutex);

        if(rand() % 2 > 0) {
            dl_push(&dl, rand() % 100, isL);
            //dl_print(&dl);
            current++;
        } else {
            dl_pop(&dl, rand() % 100);
            current++;
        }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&count_mutex);
    }
    return NULL;
}

// main function
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    pthread_mutex_t count_mutex;
    pthread_mutex_init(&count_mutex, NULL);

    // parameter indicates minimum (and initial) dlist size
    int minimum_size = atoi(argv[1]);

    // dlist initial setup
    dl_initialise(&dl);

    // allocate initial block
    dl_initialise_block(&dl, minimum_size - 2); // dlists always contain 2 items after initialisation

    // worker thread initialisation
    pthread_t threads[2];
    int tL = 1;
    int tR = 0;
    pthread_create(&threads[0], NULL, do_work, (void *)&tL);
    pthread_create(&threads[1], NULL, do_work, (void *)&tR);

    // synchronisation of worker threads with the main one
    pthread_join(threads[0], NULL);
    pthread_join(threads[1], NULL);

    // END OF TEST DATA

    dl_print(&dl); // output the state of the dlist

    dl_freeMemoryConditional(&dl); // free the memory occupied by the dlist

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should not make assumptions about how much memory is in use, even the numbers reported by the operating system are usually off by quite a lot due to the file system cache occupying what is left.

Comment: You might want to read some book about [Garbage Collection](http://gchandbook.com/), at least for the terminology and the insights it could provide; see also wikipage on [C dynamic memory allocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation). Be aware of [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space). Notice that `free` is often not releasing memory to the OS, but simply marking a memory zone reusable by future `malloc`

Comment: What do you mean by _capacity of the system_?